# Problems sending a Hello world from watch to the parent app

Tags: android, wear-os, deprecated

First of all, sorry if my English is not perfect.

On the matter. In the last 2 days I've been trying to send a simple "Hello World" from my wearable with wear os to my parent phone app. It seems easy but I'm having problems, and all the information I find on the web is deprecated.

I know I'm being very vague but the truth is I don't have much to work with. I need the example to try to advance more on my proyect, and the android developer info isn't helping me.

Comment: look into broadcast receivers.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. This is a place to improve your solution or find a solution for a strange problem you're facing. If you are new to coding and want to self learn - I would recommend you to look for tutorials and example in the language you need, just google something along the lines: "android tutorials". Sites like github are full with open source projects where you can learn and find excellent examples too. Good luck

Comment: What have you tried so far? What is it that doesn't work (sending, receiving etc)? If you can add some more details about the issue you're facing someone might be able to help you out. Also, sharing relevant code is usually a good way to engage people.

Comment: please do refer this example https://github.com/Goldenmace/Mobile-To-Wear-and-Wear-To-Mobile-Communication